# Can not select with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I'm making a simple form which contains bootstrap and quill editor same time. And when I click the "Send" button Jquery selects the value of bootstrap form fields but not quill editor's. Also I will send this datas to my API. I'm new at frontend things.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="form-container" class="container">
        <form id="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-14">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <br />
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title-field">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nickanme">Nickname</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" id="nickname-field">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <label for="editor">Story</label>
                <input name="editor" type="hidden" id="quill-editor-t">
                <div id="editor-container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    var toolbarOptions = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'];
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbarOptions
        },
        theme: 'snow',
        placeholder: 'Tell your story'
    });
    var apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/"
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        var data = {
            title: $("#title-field").val(),
            nickname: $("#nickname-field").val(),
            body: $("#quill-editor-t").val()
        }
        console.log(data)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: apiUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Successfully sent to database")
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Could not send to database");
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So when I click the "send" button, "body" returns null. As you can see I also set it up: `body: $("#quill-editor-t").val()`

I dont know how can I handle this? I just want to read my quill editor's content with jquery but I dont know how can I do that.

Comment: `quill-editor-t` is a hidden input and i cant see you givet it a value? what's the value you expected to get?

Comment: I've tested your code in a fiddle and it seems to work when I put a value in the hidden input. It gets the value in `data`. My guess is that you don't pass any value to that input when you are submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the quill content using **[`.getContents()`](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents)** instead :

```
var data = {
    title: $("#title-field").val(),
    nickname: $("#nickname-field").val(),
    body: quill.getContents();
}
```

Hope this helps.

And there is no need of `hidden` field with `id="quill-editor-t"`.